# Scrolling on gridView not allowing me to save selected data

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a gridView which I populate using a Custom Adapter. The custom adapter is slightly complex as on each cell I populate different kinds of widgets based on the user requirements. This is working fine and I am able to scroll and set values to specific widgets.

When it comes time to save, I loop through the GridView's children and pass the values on to a JSON. This works too but only for the visible children.

Can someone tell me how I can get the values of the widgets that are in cells but not visible on the grid view because I have scrolled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem occurs on `ListView` and `GridView` because android in these components destroy and recreate views.

If you need to pass this problem you have two choices:

**First**: Add some modification on you Adapter to save value for each row or item in your `GridView`.

**Second**: use `RecyclerView` because this problem will not appear in it.

I prefer the second choice. `RecyclerView` better than `Grid` and `ListView`.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I have changed my Grid View to a Recycler View but am facing the same problem. RecyclerView.getChildCount only returns the visible no. of children. I then tried the layoutManger but it had the same issue. LayoutManager.getItemCount() did retrieve the correct number of children but I am not able to access any view when it is not visible. I am using getChildAt(). Did I miss something?

Comment: @Prem you need to perform action on `RecyclerView` items?

Comment: Yes. There are a few widgets like Checkboxes and RadioButtons which are populated on the RecyclerView. On pressing save, I need to get all these values and pass them to a JSON. Is there a way?

Comment: @Prem Yes, you can do this, implements action listeners in RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: Please check this link http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/recycler-view-handling-onitemtouch-for.html